# rmagick convert svg to png

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I've tried almost all steps available on 1-2 results page of google results "convert svg to png rmagick"
None of them actually work.
I'm just resizing every image that gets uploaded

```
image = Magick::Image.read(logo.tempfile.path).first
image.resize_to_fit!(150, 96)
image.to_blob
```

But this fails for SVG. So, checking here to see if someone has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just call [the write method](https://rmagick.github.io/image3.html#write) with the filename you want the image to have.

image.write("myimage.png")